# How to query Two different classNames queries one result set?

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I have this structure:

```
UserDetails with a GeoPoint
Locations with a GeoPoint
```

I would like to show both results with nearGeoPoint queries in one tableView with different cell layouts, but is the structure going to work, because you can not use 2 different classNames with compound queries with Parse.

How to solve this, so I have one result set (array) sorted on userLocationPoint nearest both UserDetails and Locations?

Comment: Why do you want to download stuff from two seperate classes in one array of pfobjects?

Comment: What do you suggest that I make an other ClassName structure

    UserDetails and Clubs and make Locations a Classname with pointers to Clubs and UserDetails and in Locations store there GeoPoint ??

Comment: I dont know what you wanna accomplish, design of the db is very important and since parse uses NoSQL databasee you should design it differently than relation dbs